# When the TCP connection close in this code?

Tags: go, networking, tcp

When I read this [opensource code.](https://github.com/LiamHaworth/go-tproxy/blob/ef7efd7f24ed7e9bf8f479c890c81ce7db27000e/example/tproxy_example.go#L159)

I have two questions about the two functions:

```
func listenTCP() {
    for {
        conn, err := tcpListener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            if netErr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && netErr.Temporary() {
                log.Printf("Temporary error while accepting connection: %s", netErr)
            }

            log.Fatalf("Unrecoverable error while accepting connection: %s", err)
            return
        }

        go handleTCPConn(conn)  // check below
    }
}


func handleTCPConn(conn net.Conn) {
    log.Printf("Accepting TCP connection from %s with destination of %s", conn.RemoteAddr().String(), conn.LocalAddr().String())
    defer conn.Close()
    
    remoteConn, err := conn.(*tproxy.Conn).DialOriginalDestination(false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to original destination [%s]: %s", conn.LocalAddr().String(), err)
        return
    } 
    defer remoteConn.Close()

    var streamWait sync.WaitGroup
    streamWait.Add(2)

    streamConn := func(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
        io.Copy(dst, src)
        streamWait.Done()
    }

    go streamConn(remoteConn, conn)
    go streamConn(conn, remoteConn)

    streamWait.Wait()
}
```

Based on my understanding, I draw this diagram:

[image]

You see, the handleTCPConn created two goroutines for transmitting two direction(left -> right; right -> left)'s traffic,

My questions are:

1. You see the code use `sync.WaitGroup`, if they only send `left-> right` traffic, there is no traffic in opposite direction, so the `handleTCPConn` will not end, right? if it is, the `listenTCP` for loop will create many of those `handleTCPConn` function calls, is there nothing wrong with this program?
2. Every time the `handleTCPConn` is used, it will create a TCP connection to the remote server.

```
remoteConn, err := conn.(*tproxy.Conn).DialOriginalDestination(false)
```

My question is still in question 1, you can see that the `handleTCPConn` transmit the traffic once in both directions, and then ends it, whether the TCP connection is closed when does handleTCPConn end?
if they only transmit part of the data of a file(as per the application layer view), whether it is closed too? (i mean, if A->B->C: part data , then C->B->A: ACK ) .

Comment: The *socket* is closed when you close it. The *connection* is closed when both sides have closed their socket endpoints.

Comment: how to correspond to the TCP states?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What you have to do is close the socket.

Comment: use  `LISTEN` `SYN_RCVD`, `ESTABLISHED` ... to represent every step of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per the golang docs, https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy

> Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs. It returns the number of bytes copied and the first error encountered while copying, if any.

So when you start this program up, it will sit there and wait for you to hit the 'proxy', and send your bytes from the source to the destination... when the destination responds it will copy all those bytes back. if the destination doesn't write any bytes **and** doesn't close the connection i believe it'll sit there forever, waiting for the far side to either close the socket or respond.

Same is true if you make this connection and the remote sides starts sending data (without a request first). If the "local" side never sends any bytes and doesn't close the connection this code would wait forever as well.

As long as the remote side closes the connection gracefully, this code should exit with "0" bytes received and no error. If the remote side sends a reset, you should get an error of some kind